# LG DVD Player not able to see Nero Media Home 4

Tags: router, dvd, blu-ray, nero

I'm stumped with a DVD Player/PC Issue.

Here's the problem. I bought an LG Blu Ray DVD Player and want to connect to my computer to stream videos/music/pictures. The BLU Ray player came with Nero Media Home 4 Essentials. I installed the software and shared some folders.

I plugged my Blu Ray Player into my router and it picked up an IP. It can connect to the internet, download updates and even watch Youtube movies.

But, for some reason, the Player cannot see my PC. I've tried everything. I've even tried other software like XBMC, TVersity, Windows Media Centre, but the Blu ray player is not picking up the PC at all.

Is this a issue on the router? Note my Blu Ray Player and PC both use Dynamic IPs.

Do both need Static IPs?

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Update. 2012/03/07

I'm running Windows 7 64 bit yes. I'm PC literate, so have checked the basics. On my router, I can see that the Router has given the DVD Player a IP Address. I can ping this IP. Here is the config of the router.

```
Router IP is 10.0.0.3
BLU Ray Player IP is 10.0.0.4
My PC Ip is 10.0.0.5
```

I've followed the tutorials, but on my PC, when I go to Media Streaming Options, it doesn't show the BLU Ray Player as a media device.

Comment: Are you running firewall software on your PC (the Windows one included)? It might be blocking the DNLA traffic they need to communicate. Try turning it off temporarily and giving it another shot.

Comment: I checked. The only one which was running was Windows Defener. I turned it off to no avail. Also, Firewalls are disabled.

Comment: Can tou tell us the exact model of your BluRay player? Can you tell me if this represents your network: Internet-router-computer,dvdplayer,etc

Comment: Hi There. This is my configuration:
DVD Player (LG Blu Ray system) connected via LAN cable to Router. DVD Player is picking up Router because I can watch Youtube etc.
PC is connected to the same router. Internet is working on the PC. 
The only thing that is not working, is that the DVD Player cannot see the PC. It does not even pick up a Networked computer. Both Router and computer are using Dynamic (DHCP) IP addresses.

The BLU Ray system is : 
LG 5,1 3D Blu-ray Tall Boy Home Theatre System. Modal number HB806TH

Comment: Do you see the new writer with [VSO Inspector](http://vso-software.fr/) or [InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/) ?
Does it change when running respective programs "as administrator"?
If not - connection is bad.
If yes - you need to update Nero software (if it did come with different maker's drive it will ignore foreign drives even after all updates applied)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified your Windows version, so I assume it's Windows 7.

First you should check whether the player is connected to the network correctly, or might be in a different subnet of IP range addresses. The network itself should be defined as Home.

Open up the Windows Explorer and click on Network. Tell us what you see and if the player is visible in any way. It might be a good idea to post a screenshot of what you see.

If you have a way of finding out the IP address of the player, please post it and that of your PC. Try to ping the player.

Have a look at the video [Usage Guide - How to Setup DLNA on Windows 7 Operating System](http://www2.panasonic.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/vSupportHowToGuideDetail?storeId=15001&idval=UCM_STG_CNT_051244&catname=Blu-ray%20Disc™%20Players&title=Usage%20Guide%20-%20%20How%20to%20Setup%20DLNA%20on%20Windows%207%20Operating%20System&cm_sp=DMP-BDT310-Support%20HowToGuide-_-Middle-_-Usage%20Guide%20-%20%20How%20to%20Setup%20DLNA%20on%20Windows%207%20Operating%20System). Although it is for another player model, it might be useful.

The [LG page for HB806TH](http://www.lg.com/africa_en/support/product/support-product-profile.jsp?customerModelCode=HB806TH&matchedModelCode=6400003851&searchEngineModelCode=HB806TH&initialTab=warranty&targetPage=support-product-profile#) contains a firmware update : Better check that this version is installed. I also notice that your player can update itself via the Internet.

The above LG page also contains your manual. Although it is very skimpy on details, you might
verify that you have setup correctly Nero MediaHome 4 Essentials (page 51). Firmware self-update is described on page 50.

Comment: Hi There. I have udated the initial question with some updates. Thank you very much for your advice so far.

Comment: Does the device show up in any way on the Network Map (see [this thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/124871-network-map-dlna-problems.html)) ? iPV6 is also mentioned there as a potential problem, so try enabling/disabling it. Does your router support iPV6 ? As a note: the LG documentation only mentions Wi-Fi for sharing, not LAN.

Comment: Hi there. An update. I managed to get it all working by connecting directly between pc and blu ray player.. Maybe a port forwarding issue?

Comment: Maybe also a firewall issue on the router ?

Comment: I'll try to check all the configs on the router. Any idea what it might be? Firewall, Port Forwarding, UPNP?

Comment: Only firewall applies, and in your case for the internal LAN, not Internet. I believe DLNA uses ports from 52100 to 52199, UPnP uses UDP port 1900 and TCP port 2869. Some routers list these services already by name. As a start you could *very temporarily* disable the router's firewall (or firewalls - as some routers have external and internal ones).

Comment: Ok, I'll go and play around with it tongiht. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

The manual says (page 47):
"Shared folder or files from media server are not displayed on the device list.
The player is not connected to the local area network that your media server are connected."

So they think if you have made selections on the player and Nero properly it should work automatically even with dynamic IP addresses.  One thing to check is if the router might be firewalling or not bridging between LAN addresses.

However the manual also says: 
"Before you install Nero MediaHome 4 Essentials, check the system requirement shown below.

Windows® XP (Service Pack 2 or higher), Windows Vista® (no Service Pack required), Windows® XP Media Center Edition 2005 (Service Pack 2 or higher), Windows Server® 2003

Windows Vista® 64-bit edition (application runs in 32-bit mode)"

So Windows 7 is not supported.  There may be a workaround, as harrymc pointed out, setting up a different DLNA server, since its a standard that the player supposedly meets/can work with.

see harrymc link in post^^
"Usage Guide - How to Setup DLNA on Windows 7 Operating System"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dlna

Alternately get a player that supports win7 64 bit.  (See online manuals before buying)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @conspiritech. I have however establishes that the problem is not Operating system related because when connecting the LAN cable directly to my computer and bypassing my ADSL Router, everything works fine. The player picks up Nero and even the normal windows profiles. So, i'm left with troubleshooting router issues. Thanks